# How do I share dynamically loaded class outside scope

Tags: javascript, importerror, es6-modules

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) it's possible to do like this:

```
let myModule;

if (typeof window === "undefined") {
   myModule = await import("module-used-on-server");
} else {
   myModule = await import("module-used-in-browser");
}
```

But trying to use this module export (myClass.js):

```
export class MyClass {
   constructor(){
      console.log('MyClass Constructed');
   }
}
```

this code (window.initialize() called from a callback) gives me a "*MyClass is not a constructor*" error in the console (Chrome):

```
let MyClass;

window.initialize = async () => {
   MyClass = await import('../modules/myClass.js');
   let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
}
```

This code works though:

```
window.initialize = async () => {
   let { MyClass } = await import('../modules/myClass.js');
   let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
}
```

So how do I make the class constructor available outside the function scope?

Thx ;)

This will work but "feels wrong":

```
let newMyClass = null;

window.initialize = async () => {
   let { MyClass } = await import('../modules/myClass.js');
   newMyClass = () => { return new MyClass(); }
   let myClassInstance = new newMyClass();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are exporting your class like so:

```
export class MyClass {
^^^^^^
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
class MyClass { ... }
export { MyClass }
```

That's the reason why `import` doesn't return it without need to use the destructuring. I believe you can use this approach instead

```
let MyClass

window.initialize = async () => {
   let myClassImport = await import('../modules/myClass.js');
   MyClass = myClassImport.MyClass
   let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
}
```

Or simply add this class to the global window scope like so

```
window.initialize = async () => {
   let myClassImport = await import('../modules/myClass.js');
   window.MyClass = myClassImport.MyClass;
   let myClassInstance = new MyClass();
}
```

Comment: Thx! No destructuring was the issue..